# Error Initialize ManagedBean with Spring JSF 2.0 Hibernate Maven

Tags: spring, jsf, maven, jpa

i am working with JSF 2.0 , Spring, Hibernate and i'm having a problem with a initialization of a ManagedBean.

Here is the error:

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/cadastroDeProdutoAdminSistemas.xhtml]
 com.sun.faces.mgbean.ManagedBeanCreationException: Não é possível criar instância     para·a classe: com.catalogor3e.controller.PesquisaSistemasAdminBean.
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:193)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.build(BeanBuilder.java:102)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.createAndPush(BeanManager.java:409)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanManager.create(BeanManager.java:269)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.resolveBean(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:244)
at com.sun.faces.el.ManagedBeanELResolver.getValue(ManagedBeanELResolver.java:116)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
at com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
at org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:185)
at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagValueExpression.getValue(TagValueExpression.java:109)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:194)
at javax.faces.component.ComponentStateHelper.eval(ComponentStateHelper.java:182)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getValue(UIData.java:731)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTable.getValue(DataTable.java:729)
at org.primefaces.component.api.UIData.getDataModel(UIData.java:575)
at javax.faces.component.UIData.getRowCount(UIData.java:356)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeTbody(DataTableRenderer.java:579)
at org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeRegularTable(DataTableRenderer.java:220)
at   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeMarkup(DataTableRenderer.java:192)
at   org.primefaces.component.datatable.DataTableRenderer.encodeEnd(DataTableRenderer.java:74)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChild(CoreRenderer.java:55)
at org.primefaces.renderkit.CoreRenderer.renderChildren(CoreRenderer.java:43)
at org.primefaces.component.layout.LayoutUnitRenderer.encodeEnd(LayoutUnitRenderer.java:51)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1764)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1760)
at   com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    Hibernate: select estado0_.id as id3_, estado0_.nome_estado as nome2_3_ from estado    estado0_
at   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:936)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
       Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.catalogor3e.controller.PesquisaSistemasAdminBean.<init>(PesquisaSistemasAdminBean.java:51)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:525)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:372)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:325)
at com.sun.faces.mgbean.BeanBuilder.newBeanInstance(BeanBuilder.java:188)
... 58 more
```

here is my ManagedBean:

```
@ManagedBean(name="pesquisaSistemasAdminBean")
@SessionScoped
public class PesquisaSistemasAdminBean{

@ManagedProperty(value = "#{filtroEtiquetaCidadeSistemaBean}")    
private FiltroEtiquetaCidadeSistemaBean filtroEtiquetaCidadeSistemaBean;

@ManagedProperty("#{facadeService}")
private FacadeService service;

private DataModel<Sistema> listaSistemas ;

//variáveis para filtro
private int idCategoriaParaFiltro = -1;
private List<String> idsDeComponentesParaFiltro = new ArrayList<String>();
private int idFabricanteParaFiltro = -1;


public PesquisaSistemasAdminBean() {
    this.listaSistemas = new ListDataModel<Sistema>  (this.service.getServiceSistemas().filtrarSistemaConstrutivo(null, null, null, null, null));
}


//retorna todas as categorias(tipos) dos sistemas existentes no banco
public List<CategoriaSistema> getListaDeCategorias(){
    List<CategoriaSistema> listaDeCategorias = this.service.getServiceCategoriaDeSistemas().getTodasAsCategoriasDeSistemas();
    return listaDeCategorias;
}

public void filtrarSistemaConstrutivo(){
     CategoriaSistema categoriaDeSistema = null;
     Fabricante fabricante = null;
     ZonaBioclimatica zona = null;
     Etiqueta etiqueta = null;
     List<CategoriaCamada> listaDeCategoriasDeComponentes = null;
     if(this.idCategoriaParaFiltro != -1){
         categoriaDeSistema =  this.service.getServiceCategoriaDeSistemas().getCategoriaPeloID(idCategoriaParaFiltro);
     }
     if(this.idFabricanteParaFiltro != -1){
         fabricante = this.service.getServiceFabricante().getFabricantePeloID(idCategoriaParaFiltro);
     }
     if(this.filtroEtiquetaCidadeSistemaBean.getZonaBioclimaticaParaFiltro() != null){
         zona = this.filtroEtiquetaCidadeSistemaBean.getZonaBioclimaticaParaFiltro();
     }
     if(this.filtroEtiquetaCidadeSistemaBean.getIdEtiqueta() != -1){
         etiqueta = this.service.getServiceCidadeEstado().getEtiquetaPeloID(this.filtroEtiquetaCidadeSistemaBean.getIdEtiqueta());
     }

     if(!this.idsDeComponentesParaFiltro.isEmpty()){
         listaDeCategoriasDeComponentes = new ArrayList<CategoriaCamada>();
         for(int i = 0; i < idsDeComponentesParaFiltro.size(); i++){
             CategoriaCamada categoriaCamada = this.service.getServiceCategoriaDeComponentesConstrutivos().getCategoriaComponenteConstrutivoPeloId(Integer.parseInt(idsDeComponentesParaFiltro.get(i)));
             listaDeCategoriasDeComponentes.add(categoriaCamada);
         }
     }
     this.listaSistemas = new ListDataModel<Sistema>  (this.service.getServiceSistemas().filtrarSistemaConstrutivo(categoriaDeSistema, listaDeCategoriasDeComponentes, fabricante, zona, etiqueta));
}

//retorna todos os fabricantes existentes no banco
 public List<Fabricante> getListaFabricantes(){
    List<Fabricante> listaDeFabricantes = this.service.getServiceFabricante().listaDeTodosOsFabricantes();
    return listaDeFabricantes;
}

 ///gets e sets está implementado, mas economizei código aqui!!!
```

here is my pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.mycompany</groupId>
<artifactId>catalogo</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>catalogo</name>

<properties>
    <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
<groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
<artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
<version>2.1.6</version>
</dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
   <version>2.1.10</version>
  </dependency> 

<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
  <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.0</version>
 </dependency>

 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
 <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
   <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
 </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>



<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
  <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.6.ga</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.2.GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>mysql</groupId>
  <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
  <version>5.1.15</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
  <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.6.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency> 
  <groupId>commons-collections</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-collections</artifactId>
  <version>3.1</version> 
</dependency> 

<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>4.10</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>


<dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.sql</groupId>
  <artifactId>jdbc-stdext</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
  <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.1B</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>  
  <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
  <version>3.4.1</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.primefaces.themes</groupId>
  <artifactId>all-themes</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.9</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
<groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
<version>1.2.3-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>commons-io</groupId>
<artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
<version>2.5-SNAPSHOT</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>rome</groupId>
<artifactId>rome</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
<groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
<artifactId>poi</artifactId>
<version>3.7</version>
</dependency>   
<dependency>
<groupId>com.lowagie</groupId>
<artifactId>itext</artifactId>
<version>2.0.7</version>
</dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax</groupId>
        <artifactId>javaee-web-api</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
                <compilerArguments>
                    <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                </compilerArguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>validate</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                        <silent>true</silent>
                        <artifactItems>
                            <artifactItem>
                                <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                <version>6.0</version>
                                <type>jar</type>
                            </artifactItem>
                        </artifactItems>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
<repositories>


  <repository>
        <url>http://download.java.net/maven/2/</url>
        <id>jsf20</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[jsf20]</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>
        <url>http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/</url>
        <id>jstl11</id>
        <layout>default</layout>
        <name>Repository for library Library[jstl11]</name>
    </repository>
    <repository>  
        <id>prime-repo</id>  
        <name>PrimeFaces Maven Repository</name>  
        <url>http://repository.primefaces.org</url>  
        <layout>default</layout>  
    </repository> 


        <repository>
            <releases>
            <enabled>false</enabled>
        </releases>
        <snapshots>
            <enabled>true</enabled>
        </snapshots>
        <id>apache.snapshots</id>
        <name>Apache Snapshot Repository</name>
        <url>https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/snapshots</url>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

here is my web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" 
     xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
     http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">


<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
    <param-value>Development</param-value>
</context-param>


<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>
        30
    </session-timeout>
</session-config>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>faces/index.xhtml</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<context-param>
    <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
    <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
</context-param>

   <filter-mapping> 
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>  
   <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name> 
   </filter-mapping>
   <filter> 
   <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>      
   <filter-class>org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter</filter-class> 
   </filter>    



  <context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
  </context-param>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>
     org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener
  </listener-class>
 </listener>
 <listener>
  <listener-class>
     org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
  </listener-class>
 </listener>

</web-app>
```

here is my applicationContext.xml

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
  xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- Seta anotaçoes para serem  <context:annotation-config />usadas pelo Spring -->
  <context:annotation-config />


  <!-- Define o pacote onde o Spring vai procurar por beans anotados --> 
  <context:component-scan base-package="com.catalogor3e.dao, com.catalogor3e.service"  />

  <!-- define que as transaçoes irao ser anotadas -->
  <tx:annotation-driven />



 <bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bancodedados"/>
    <property name="username" value="root"/>
    <property name="password" value="852456"/>
  </bean>

< bean id="entityManagerFactory"  class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="catalogoPU" />
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
        <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
            <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter">
                <property name="databasePlatform" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />
                <property name="showSql" value="true" /> 
            </bean>
        </property>
</bean>

<!-- Configuracao do gerente de transacoes do Spring -->
<bean id="transactionManager"   class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

</beans>
```

please, Can anybody help me with this, please?

Att,

Diego Sabino

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the root cause of your exception, it's the bottommost part. That's of the most relevance:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.catalogor3e.controller.PesquisaSistemasAdminBean.<init>(PesquisaSistemasAdminBean.java:51)
```

So, something is `null` inside the bean's constructor while the code is attempting to access/invoke it. Let's look at the constructor:

```
public PesquisaSistemasAdminBean() {
    this.listaSistemas = new ListDataModel<Sistema>  (this.service.getServiceSistemas().filtrarSistemaConstrutivo(null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

Hey, you're trying to access `service` which is declared as a managed property. You seem to be expecting that managed property injection works as follows:

```
PesquisaSistemasAdminBean pesquisaSistemasAdminBean; // Declare bean.
pesquisaSistemasAdminBean.setService(facadeService); // Set service.
pesquisaSistemasAdminBean = new PesquisaSistemasAdminBean(); // Invoke constructor.
```

But this is impossible. It is technically simply not possible to set the service as an instance variable before the instance is ever constructed. Actually, the following is what really happens:

```
PesquisaSistemasAdminBean pesquisaSistemasAdminBean; // Declare bean.
pesquisaSistemasAdminBean = new PesquisaSistemasAdminBean(); // Invoke constructor.
pesquisaSistemasAdminBean.setService(facadeService); // Set service.
```

That explains why the service is still `null` inside the constructor. If you intend to perform some business logic based on injected dependencies directly after bean's construction, then you should be using a `@PostConstruct` annotated method.

So, you need to **replace** the constructor

```
public PesquisaSistemasAdminBean() {
    this.listaSistemas = new ListDataModel<Sistema>  (this.service.getServiceSistemas().filtrarSistemaConstrutivo(null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

by a `@PostConstruct` method

```
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    this.listaSistemas = new ListDataModel<Sistema>  (this.service.getServiceSistemas().filtrarSistemaConstrutivo(null, null, null, null, null));
}
```

The method name is fully to your choice, by the way.

Comment: BalusC can you help with this problem too?? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16083199/lazyinitialization-with-jpa-spring-hibernate-jsf-2-0

Comment: That's not a JSF problem. Just a JPA problem.

Comment: Ok, Thank you anyway... I have this problem with lazyInitialization that occurs due opening and closing connection with dataBase... But i am using Spring, witch is responsible for manage that. And i don't know what to do!